# Basic SSD disk corrupted after a clean Windows reformat

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery, chkdsk

As the title stated, I've been using the disk (Adata SU650) for quite a long time and never had issues with it until lately I clean reformatted my PC and realized during the initial setup there's a disk with `0MB`:

[image]

This wasn't the case with my previous reformat, but I proceeded anyway to later check in the Disk Manager, which shows up as:

[image]

*Explaining the picture above I have:*

- 1 Kingston SSD for Windows Boot
- 2 Seagate Barracuda HDD for redundancy Main Disk
- Lastly, 2 SSD Adata SU650

Methods I tried:

1. Trying to initialize just gives me an `A device which does not exist was specified` error.
2. I've also tried using testdisk to check if it's recoverable, but the disk doesn't show up.
3. Using `mountvol` to run `chkdsk` also gives the same result as number 2.
4. Using software such as AOMEI to rebuild the disk, then recover doesn't help as it appears as `0KB` and couldn't recover any data, nor EaseUs, where the disk also doesn't appear within the list at all.
5. I also can't reformat or delete any volume/partition of the SSD as it appears `0KB` in the system.
6. Flash Update BIOS in case of BIOS corrupt doesn't resolve the issue either.
7. Uninstalling the driver in Device Manager or Searching for updates resulted in no changes.
8. Using Adata ToolBox, the disk doesn't appear as well :(

[image]

What can or should I do here? Can someone help? It's preferable if I could recover the SSD as there's data I want within it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried shutting download the system, unplugging (everything), wait about 1 minute, remove all drives, one at a time and reseating them, one at a time? Sometimes the lines need to be reseated, memory is also like this, sometimes. Good luck.

Comment: FWIW, my best advice to you is to get an external USB to SATA enclosure or a similar external USB to SATA connector and try to mount it that way. Your best bet is to do that to recover data and consider the drive dead.

Comment: @vssher I haven't tried resolving through hardware and as Giacomo1968's suggested. I'm getting myself the SATA to USB Cable to test it out.

Comment: I would favor an external device with a power supply such as an exclosure or a docking station over just a cable connection even if it is a SSD just to rule out any power supply issues.

Answer (score 0):

A disk can fail, especially after being used for "quite a long time".

If the disk can no longer be seen or recognized or initialized
by Windows, then it has simply failed.

If you had irreplaceable data on the disk, it can be recovered by
professional disk-recovery companies, although this is not a
cheap service.
Otherwise, it's time to buy a new disk.

Comment: I see... that's hard to believe as I've only used it for two years :\

Comment: The average number for a disk's lifetime includes disks that go far beyond, but also disks that fail much too soon. It's only a matter of luck. Some disks are guaranteed for 5 years or more - if yours is still under guarantee, then you can ask the manufacturer to recover your data and replace the disk.

Comment: SSD firmware is much more complex than HDD's. Often it's not even the device physically failing but purely firmware issue that bricks a SSD. Since this firmware is so much o more complex, the room for this type of error has increased.

Comment: @harrymc Yeah I'm going to do just that, but before so, I'll going to do a final test with a USB to SATA Cable, as Giacomo1968 suggested, before claiming warranty from the manufacturer.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I see, is the firmware unique to each individual disk? I'm worried if it'll affect my other SSD as they're under the same brand and model.

Comment: Very likely they are the same firmware, but the problem is rather with the hardware. If you look at [Amazon customer's reviews](https://www.amazon.com/ADATA-SU650-240GB-Internal-ASU650SS-240GT-C/product-reviews/B07CX1ZKCH?pageNumber=2) you will find for one user : "This is the second Adata SSD that has failed for me in less than 2 years". So be careful.

Comment: @harrymc; Sure it could be hardware, but multiple disks failing does not per se point to hardware. At the same time firmware can corrupt due to failing hardware (NAND). Main point is, answer is correct, any storage device can fail at any time.